# Automatically jump to the next EditText when i enter a number inXamarin Android (Visual Studio 2012)

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

[image: Snapshot]

I have four EditText in android layout.

Here's the code:

```
     <EditText
        android:inputType="numberPassword"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:id="@+id/passcode1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
        android:cursorVisible="true"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColorHint="@android:color/background_dark"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:maxLength="1"
        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
        android:paddingTop="25px"
        android:nextFocusForward="@+id/passcode2"
        android:background="@drawable/Border"
        android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/Pink_Cursor"
        android:singleLine="true"
        style="@android:style/Widget.EditText" />
    <EditText
        android:inputType="numberPassword"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:id="@+id/passcode2"
        android:layout_marginLeft="120dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
        android:cursorVisible="true"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColorHint="@android:color/background_dark"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:maxLength="1"
        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
        android:paddingTop="25px"
        android:nextFocusForward="@+id/passcode3"
        android:background="@drawable/Border"
        android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/Pink_Cursor"
        android:singleLine="true" />
    <EditText
        android:inputType="numberPassword"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:id="@+id/passcode3"
        android:layout_marginLeft="200dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
        android:cursorVisible="true"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColorHint="@android:color/background_dark"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:maxLength="1"
        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
        android:paddingTop="25px"
        android:background="@drawable/Border"
        android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/Pink_Cursor"
        android:singleLine="true" />
    <EditText
        android:inputType="numberPassword"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:id="@+id/passcode4"
        android:layout_marginLeft="280dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
        android:cursorVisible="true"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColorHint="@android:color/background_dark"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:maxLength="1"
        android:imeOptions="actionGo"
        android:paddingTop="25px"
        android:background="@drawable/Border"
        android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/Pink_Cursor"
        android:singleLine="true" />
```

I have given maxlength one.If i enter a number, the cursor should automatically jump to the next EditText.
I have used Imeoptions(Next), but we have to click Next in SoftKeyboard.
I want to automatically jump to the next EditText when i enter a number?
How to do it in Android Xamarin?

Comment: In the 'changed' event of a EditText you could set the focus to the next one...

Comment: @DieterMeemken:Sorry I did't get you. I am new to Xamarin so..

Comment: The EditText control should have some kind of 'changed' event that is triggered, when the text inside is changed. You should subscribe for this event and in the call back function you set the focus to the next EditText like editText2.SetFocus() or similar.